# Selling a website with AdSense income - how do I separate that that domain from AdSense Account

Tags: google-adsense

I am considering selling one of my websites - which includes the domain as well as AdSense income.  I have other websites in my AdSense account - how can I separate that domain / website from my existing AdSense account?

Comment: You should only remove Adsense code snippet from that specific website. Check with your developer how it was inserted.

Comment: Thank you!   That is easy enough.  I appreciate your help.  Sibylle